# Python Regex Optional Second Word Within a Group

Tags: python, regex

I wrote the following Regular Expression

```
m = re.match('.+SPELL_DAMAGE,.+,"([A-Z][a-z]+)",.+"([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+!?)",\d+x\d+,(\d+)',line)
```

I want the second group to basically say "Look for one word or two words that sometimes end in an exclamation point.

```
([A-Z][a-z]+\s[A-Z][a-z]+!?)
```

Right now the regular expression only works for the second group having exactly two words. I'm not sure how to use the `?` Regular Expression with `()` inside of a group.

I was thinking `([A-Z][a-z](+\s[A-Z][a-z]+!?)?)` in order to make the second word entirely optional but I get an error about `sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat`

So in short the second group should match "White" or "White House" or "White House!"

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`([A-Z][a-z](+\s[A-Z][a-z]+!?)?)` has the first `+` on the wrong side of the parens.

Try `([A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+!?)?)`

```
>>> re.match(r"([A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+!?)?)", "White House").groups()
('White House', ' House')
```

Aside: to get rid of the pointless "extra words" group, you can use non-grouping parentheses: `(?:...)` instead of `(...)`

so:

```
>>> re.match(r"([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+!?)?)", "White House").groups()
('White House',)
```